# Best 2 TB 7200 RPM laptop spinning disk drive?

Tags: hard-disk, high-end

Is there currently a 2 TB or greater laptop HDD that can attain 7200 RPM or more? If there's more than one, which of them would be the fastest or most reliable?

Comment: This is normally where your use-case would recommend an SSD.  Is there a reason you're not looking into that option?

Comment: @CDove - I already have several SSDs in my laptop, as well as a 1 TB 7200 RPM HDD. I'm looking to upgrade the HDD.

Comment: HDD is old technology and is being replaced by SSD.   While expensive, 1-2 TB SSD are available, perform better, and physically last longer than HDD.  If it's within your budget, I'd do that.   The only alternative I can think of is an SAS drive (i.e. Quantum Fireball) that can run at 15000RPM, but those stop at about 600GB because SSD have effectively replaced them and SAS is uncommon and probably not in your laptop.

Comment: @CDove - I already have plenty of solid state storage in my laptop. Currently I have 3 TB, which I might upgrade by 1 TB soon. I also have a 1 TB HDD in there, and I'd rather not buy a 1 TB+ SSD to replace it with at the moment.

Comment: The faster it spins the more damage will be done when you accidentally sit on it or drop.  If I had $1 for ever user that said it would never happen to them and it did I would be retiring today.

Comment: @cybernard - I'm not sure my laptop would notice if I sat on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes, but don't get one if you can avoid it.

There are only two HDDs that fit the requirements you have: the Seagate [ST2000NX0253](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/VpgPxr/seagate-internal-hard-drive-st2000nx0253) and the [ST2000NX0303](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/zNPzK8/seagate-internal-hard-drive-st2000nx0303). At ~$300 each, these things are ridiculously expensive; you're looking at [SSD tier pricing](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/internal-hard-drive/#sort=ppgb&f=3&t=0) for a spinning drive.

My recommendation would be to instead get a cheaper 5400RPM drive–my recommendation goes to the [Seagate ST2000LM015](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/2fGj4D/seagate-barracuda-2tb-25-5400rpm-internal-hard-drive-st2000lm015) (currently $71.99) because of the reasonably large cache and Seagate's relatively solid reputation–and then set aside some SSD space as a cache, depending on the write endurance of your drive and OS/platform.